# Rails - Create nil value when performing grouped functions on filtered out values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Let's say I have a `User` table connected to a `Payment` table. I want to find the sum of all of a user's payments, even if they didn't make any. I might do something like:

```
User.left_joins(:payments).group(:id).pluck(:id, "SUM(amount)")
```

This would return nil values for the users who don't have a payment record. However, if I apply any kind of filtering, that aspect is lost. For example:

```
User.left_joins(:payments).where("payment_date > '2021-01-01'").group(:id).pluck(:id, "SUM(amount)")
```

The output will only contain users who made a payment after 2021-01-01. There will be no mention of users who only made payments before 2021 or never made a payment at all. Is there a way to maintain this information as nil or 0, similar to how it was done in the first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct an explicit condition on an OUTER JOIN creates an INNER JOIN. In order for this to perform as requested you would need a complex join condition like

```
join_condition = Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(
    Payment.arel_table,
    Arel::Nodes::On.new(
      Payment.arel_attribute(:user_id).eq(User.arel_attribute(:id))
        .and(Payment.arel_attribute(:payment_date).gt('2021-01-01'))
    )
  )
User.joins(join_condition).group(:id).pluck(:id, "SUM(amount)")
```

This will result in something akin to

```
SELECT 
  users.id,
  SUM(amount) as exp1 
FROM 
  users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id
    AND payments.payment_date > '2021-01-01' 
GROUP BY 
  users.id
```

Comment: Also possible User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN payments ON payments.user_id = users.id AND payment_date > '2021-01-01'"), if the params are coming from the database maybe he doesn't need to sanitize them. Anyway this would avoid arel which can get complex

Comment: @Joel_Blum while you are correct in that your implementation will work, it is unlikely this filtering is coming from the database. Also I prefer Arel implementations because they are highly dynamic, database agnostic, and virtuously sanitized. All of these features seem well worth any consideration for thier complexity, which might suggest why even rails is enforcing Arel over raw string as of rails 6

Comment: Interesting I wasn't aware of that, do you have some link / PR to this enforcing?

Comment: @Joel_Blum First of all I should have said "beginning to enforce Arel over raw strings". Here are some of the changes  [ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/UnknownAttributeReference.html), [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27947), currently these changes have a limited scope however it suggests a leaning in a new direction for rails.

Comment: @Joel_Blum That being said ongoing improvements to the query interface may phase out raw SQL naturally as the underpinning of arel become better exposed and the need (ease of use) for raw SQL is lessened. For instance [This PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42029) seems a bit naive at the moment but conceptually I think something like this has an immense amount of promise in the future.